# The superscript is too faraway

Tags: superscripts

I have a norm symbol `\| f \|_{{\tilde L}^{k^*}}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\| f \|_{{\tilde L}^{k^*}}
\]

\[
k^*
\]

\end{document}
```

The resulted rendering is

[image]

The superscript `*` seems to faraway from `k`, which is not my intention. Could you please elaborate on this issue? Is there a way to make it appear as usual?

Comment: It is a lot easier to see if you use `\| f \|_{{\tilde L}^{k^*}} \scriptscriptstyle k^*`, I'd say it is an artifact from the smaller sizes. No idea if it is intentional. You can always manually use `^{\!*}` or a manual amount `^{\mkern-2mu*}`